# Is it ever faster to find the max than the argmax?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

Of all the competitive programming I've ever done, I've never seen an instance where it's faster to find the max than the argmax, even though I feel like it should be possible. Any suggestions or ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, `max` is the maximum value of a function `f(x)` for all `x`, while `argmax` is the actual `x` where `f(x)` is a maximum.

An example off the top of my head where `max` is faster than `argmax`.

Pseudo-random number generators (PRNGs) in computer languages will give deterministic values based on the initial seeds. Usually a lot of care is done to ensure that the PRNG is "good" and other than providing a reproducible output for an initial seed, should behave as closely as possible to a real RNG.

For a uniform floating point PRNG, the range of `f(x)` is `0 ≤ f(x) < 1` so `max` is `1 - ε` with `ε` the smallest strictly positive floating point value depending on the internal representation. But how to find `argmax`, i.e. which `x` such that `f(x) = 1 - ε`? That would probably take a long time.

Another example which might be more accessible.

There is a well-known prime testing function which can determine if a number `N` is probably prime, with probably being very close to 1, and runs very quickly, essentially in constant time.

If the function indicates that `N` is not prime, then there exists at least one `n`, `1 < n < N` such that `N ≡ 0 mod n`, i.e. `N / n` has no remainder. Set `f(n) = N - (N % n)`, then if `N` is not prime, `max(f(n)) = N`, but for large `N`, `argmax` involves factoring `N` and is very hard to find.